# DefaultButton in Repeater with textbox and button?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a repeater, which represents a shoppingbasket. This shopping basket has an "Update quantity" and a "Delete item" button.

When you edit the quantity and click enter, I will need it to use the Update quantity button (unlike now where it uses the delete item button).

In the code I've tried fixing this by adding a "QuantityPanel" with a DefaultButton, but this doesn't solve my issue!

Any ideas?

My code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ProductBasketRepeater" runat="server" 
                onitemcommand="ProductBasketRepeater_ItemCommand" 
                onitemdatabound="ProductBasketRepeater_ItemDataBound1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="BasketEntryItem">
                <td class="ImageCol">
                    <asp:Image ID="ProductImageBox" runat="server" Width="50" />
                </td>

                <td class="NameCol">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="ProductNameHyperlink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>             
                </td>

                <td class="PriceCol">
                    <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>

                <td class="QuanCol">
                    <asp:Panel ID="QuantityPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="UpdateQuantityBtn">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuantityBox" runat="server" Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateQuantityBtn" runat="server" Text="Opdater" CommandName="UpdateQuantity"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </td>

                <td class="TotalCol">
                    <asp:Label ID="TotalPriceLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="DeleteProductBtn" runat="server" Text="Slet" CommandName="Delete"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <SeparatorTemplate>

        </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case jQuery is unavailable, you can use simple JavaScript to set to set default button for any texbox:

JS Code:

```
function clickButton(e, buttonid){
      var evt = e ? e : window.event;
      var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
      if (bt){
          if (evt.keyCode == 13){
                bt.click();
                return false;
          }
      }
}
```

ASPX page or any simple "input" textbox:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" onkeypress="return clickButton(event,'Button1')"  />
```

Code begind C#:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'" + Button1.ClientID + "')");
```

Do you need help with apply this code in repeater ?

Comment: Thanks a lot - that did the job :-) No problem with the repeater. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, this piece of code will issue a programmatic click when pressing enter in the textbox:

```
$('input[id$=QuantityBox]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next('input[id$=UpdateQuantityBtn]').click();
    }
});
```

Note: I saw a bit late you did not requested jquery specifically, but in you do, this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot - no jQuery but definetely a great solution. Thanks!